# Why does collections.Counter treat numpy.nan as equal?

Tags: python, numpy

I am surprised by the following behavior:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_list = [1,2,2, np.nan, np.nan]
>>> Counter(my_list)
Counter({nan: 2, 2: 2, 1: 1}) # Counter treats np.nan as equal and 
                              # tells me that I have two of them
>>> np.nan == np.nan          # However, np.nan's are not equal  
False
```

What is going on here?

When I use `float('nan')` instead of `np.nan`, I get the behavior I expect:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,2, float('nan'), float('nan')]
>>> Counter(my_list)
Counter({2: 2, nan: 1, 1: 1, nan: 1}) # two different nan's
>>> float('nan') == float('nan')
False
```

I am using `python 2.7.3` and `numpy 1.8.1`.

Edit:

If I do:

```
>>> a = 300
>>> b = 300
>>> a is b
False
>>> Counter([a, b])
Counter({300: 2})
```

So, `Counter` or any python `dict` considers two objects `X` and `Y` not the same if:

```
X == Y -> False

and

X is Y -> False
```

correct?

Comment: Is `np.nan is np.nan` true?

Comment: There is only a single `np.nan`, so `hash(np.nan)` is constant, so they're the same as far as dictionaries are concerned

Comment: They aren't *equal*, but `numpy.nan is numpy.nan`, whereas `float('nan') is not float('nan')`

Comment: It's not the hash, per se -- `hash(np.nan) == hash(float("nan")) == hash(0) == 0`, in CPython.  It's the identity (or lack thereof).

Comment: Convincing argument, good thing I didn't make an answer out of it :-) (no Python on this machine)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't about `numpy.nan` vs. `float("nan")`, it's that you've got two separate float nans.

```
>>> np.nan is np.nan
True
>>> float("nan") is float("nan")
False
```

and so

```
>>> Counter([1,2,2, np.nan, np.nan])
Counter({nan: 2, 2: 2, 1: 1})
>>> Counter([1,2,2, float("nan"), float("nan")])
Counter({2: 2, nan: 1, 1: 1, nan: 1})
```

but

```
>>> f = float("nan")
>>> Counter([1,2,2, f, f])
Counter({nan: 2, 2: 2, 1: 1})
```

Answer (score 5):

Python dicts (and by extension, the `Counter` subclass) generally work based on equality `==` comparison of keys. *BUT* they do an optimization that assumes that if `x is y` then `x == y`. Only if `x is not y` will the dict will fall back to comparison by equality. For most types, `x is y` implies `x == y`. It's basically only floating-point NaNs and deliberately contrived counterexamples that break this condition.

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for pointing out that the behavior is general for all dicts.